# Jquery - .on("<auto close>")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that will hide the page-title if it is visible and the drop down menu button is clicked.

```
$('.site-overlay-toggle .btn').on("click", function(){

    if ( $(".page-title").is(':visible') ) {
       $( ".page-title" ).hide();
    } else {
       $( ".page-title" ).show();   
    }

});
```

This works as long as the drop down menu is **manually clicked** open and clicked closed. If I click on a anchor link in the menu on the same page, the page will scroll down to the correct section, and the drop-down menu will **automatically close**. This will however not trigger this code.

Is there a way I can detect if the menu is closed automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `$('.site-overlay-toggle .btn').trigger('click')` in the event for anchor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have menu like this

```
<button type="btn btn-navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

This how code will loke like when menu is closed.

But if menu is open code looks like this

```
<button type="btn btn-navbar" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

So you can use function .is("collapsed") or .hasClass("collapsed") for get true if menu is closed and flase if isn´t or you can get state of atribude aria-expanded.

http://api.jquery.com/is/